# Zend server deployment

Tags: zend-framework, zend-server

I'm deploying sample Zend apps on Zend server, following official tutorials. No matter what I deploy the only thing that I can access is the hello world page (Hello world
 says hello).

How can I access real application?

host/address/public and host/address/index.php or other permutations don't work...

Comment: Are you using Zend Studio to deploy or are you deploying through Zend Server by uploading a zpk, or none of the above?

Comment: I'm deploying through Zend Server by uploading zpk

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you create your zpk file with Zend Studio there is a **deployment.xml** file that specifies some vhost settings as well as various other dependencies and triggers.

If you double click this file within Zend Studio you will be presented with a gui that helps you create this file.

The two fields of importance to this question are "**Application directory**" and "**Document Root**". If you have a Zend Framework application the most likely settings for this are:

- Application Directory: **data**
- Document Root (main public directory): **data/public**

The document root is the most important part as it defines the directory where apache executes the first file.

You then export the project into a zpk and upload that within Zend Server.

Once uploaded you will be presented with a "**Set Installation Details**" screen. There you will define the virtual host directory name.

For a simple deployment to your localhost or your server IP you can have the following:

- Display Name: **Address App**
- Virtual Host: **Default**
- Path: **address**

This will then deploy your application to: **http://localhost/address** or **http://192.168.0.*/address**

You can also deploy it with a url eg:

- Display Name: **Address App**
- Virtual Host: *click "add new"* then enter the url eg. **myaddressapp.com**
- Path: *leave blank*

This will then deploy your application to: **http://myaddressapp.com**. IF you are not deploying to a live site you can fake the url by entering a record in your [hosts file](http://goo.gl/ATW9t)

Alternatively, I started writing a blog post a while ago on how to deploy to Zend Server in a VM. This does everything automatically so you dont have to rely on exporting and importing. Here is the work in progress of the post: https://docs.google.com/document/pub?id=1bR58tXWpkezomGiv9cnkySrXxKItoEUQ6E6V9a8n46A